# Baidu in nginx access.log

Tags: nginx, logging

when I checked my nginx access.log I detected some unknown entries.

Here is an example of such an entry:

```
119.96.41.183 - - [14/Aug/2013:07:56:51 +0200] "GET http://www.baidu.com/ HTTP/1.1" 302 160 "http://www.baidu.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2$
219.154.5.176 - - [14/Aug/2013:10:48:38 +0200] "GET http://www.baidu.com/ HTTP/1.1" 302 160 "http://www.baidu.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2$
```

Also there are other Entries I do not know if I should worry about:

```
91.121.123.161 - - [11/Aug/2013:09:33:58 +0200] "POST /%70%68%70%70%61%74%68/%70%68%70?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%$
```

I am running nginx 1.4.1 with php5-fpm on Debian wheezy. As control panel I am using ISPConfig on Port 8080 (default).

What can I do?

Comment: Hum, is your nginx configured as a proxy ?

Comment: I have not configured it as an proxy. How can I check?

Comment: You would see directives named "proxy_pass" or "proxy*" in your configuration file. here, those ip addresses are asking for an external websites to YOUR server, which is exactly how you would use a proxy. And nginx responded "302" which means "Moved temporarly". So he's effectively responding like a proxy would. If this server isn't a proxy, I don't know why this happens and your question is intresting.

Comment: There is nothing like proxy in any of my configuration files, not in in /etc/nginx.conf and also not in /etc/nginx/sites-available. Can this be an issue because ISPConfig is listening on port 8080 which is normally used for proxies?

Comment: You're being scanned for various security holes. Welcome to the Internet.

Comment: So this is "just" scanning and nothing I have to worry about?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at this Q&A :
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41078/url-from-another-domain-in-my-access-log

You are asking more or less the same question.

As for the answer, apart from making sure your server is secure, there is not much you can do :)

---

*I know this is quite an old entry but it is still valid. Because I cannot leave a comment, I am replying here*